# HTML emails - do fonts cascade?

Tags: html-email, html4, email-templates

If I specify Arial as the font for a table, will that cascade down as the default font for all cells/tables within the table?

E.g would this work consistently among popular email clients?

```
<table align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
  <tr>
    <td>

       <table width="100%">
         <tr>
           <td>
             Another table - would the text here still be Arial?
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Couldn't you test this?

Answer (score 1):

Have just tested in Outlook 2013 and it fails miserably. Not sure how it fairs in the many other better clients but I guess if you want to support the shockingly bad Outlook the answer is to specify styles on every table cell.

Answer (score 1):

It will work for some clients but not for all.. especially in Outlook 2010 and 2013. (same for the percentage of the width)
The best is always to specify the wanted styles and fonts for each `<td>`
like in the following:

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100%;">

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
            Another table - The text here will be formatted for all clients
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the font in every new table tag should be sufficient. I'd just copy the style value from your initial table and reuse it for every child table.

You can specify styles on every TD if you want to, but unless something has gone badly wrong (or a new version of Outlook changes this) font styles will apply to all table cells until you enter a new table.

Something like:

```
<table align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table width="100%" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
         <tr>
           <td>
             Another table - would the text here still be Arial?
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```